# Search bar results within a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am developing an ASP .NET page in which I want to populate a gridview from the database according to a search string entered in the search 'Textbox' .There is a lot of content on the web on this matter, but none solves my problem exactly. Now, I already have a gridview with templete fields on this page which can be edited and deleted from the data base. Any hint or idea about how to get this job done.Also tell me how to bind the data only with the search results(This is the most important part).

Comment: Question isn't clear very much, but I guess you want a search functionality on a gridview ??

Comment: Yes and I want to populate the gridview with the search. I don't want to highlight the Search-key values to be highlighted, which is thre on the web in abundance

Comment: yogi ....I need some help from you.Please suggest me a way out

Comment: You need to show some code. How did you bind the current data? Are you using SqlDataSource or you are binding from code-behind? Don't make us guess!

Comment: Search box is inside grid or outside? please clarify.

Comment: do u want to do something like an AutoComplete ?

Comment: @paritosh ...Search box is outside the gridview